# Msys Git Install Path Error on Get Clone in TortoiseGIT

Tags: git, open-source, tortoisegit

I installed [Msys Git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) and [TortoiseGIT](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) x64.  Whenever I try to use the Get Clone command I am getting the error: "Msys Git Install Path Error".

The wierd thing is that I when I set it all up, it worked once and then stopped.  Now I have uninstalled and reinstalled both programs multiple times and I can not get it to work again.

[Msys Git Install Path Error http://friendfeed-media.com/82c54fedb7db8420f23782832e59ba3b54edf6e7](http://friendfeed-media.com/82c54fedb7db8420f23782832e59ba3b54edf6e7)

If this belongs on super user or something, please feel free to migrate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting your path to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

Comment: Not a problem! I just installed the exact same setup a few days ago, so it was fresh in my mind. TortoiseGit can be a tad sketchy at times.

Comment: **DOESN'T WORK** - I still get the same message.

Comment: It can be a different path, mine was "C:\msysgit\bin". You must find the path where you installed msysgit.

Answer (score 17):

you must install msysGit - http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list

Comment: anyone else having this problem should start with this!  can't believe i missed something so obvious!  duh  :)

Comment: Did TortoiseGit previously install Git at the same time? It could just be I've always had Git installed prior to installing TortoiseGit, but this just caught me out too for the first time ever.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2016: [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit) has long been obsoleted ([since early 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767174/why-is-it-that-if-you-download-git-2-0-from-the-net-you-always-get-a-1-9-4-inst/26826359#26826359)).
It has been superseded by [Git For Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) (see [its releases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/)).

It comes with a much more recent bash, based on the [64bits msys2 project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/), an independent rewrite of MSYS, based on modern Cygwin (POSIX compatibility layer) and MinGW-w64: see more at "How are msys, msys2, and msysgit related to each other?"

[TortoiseGit documentation](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html) does mention, for the `Git.exe Path` setting:

> As a general note: There is no official support for Cygwin or Msys2 git in TortoiseGit. The TortoiseGit developers only use Git for Windows.

So simply install Git for Windows and you won't have any "Msys Git Install Path Error".