# Why is it that if you download Git 2.0 from the net, you always get a 1.9.4 installer package?

Tags: git

Why is it that if you download Git 2.0 from the net, you always get a 1.9.4 installer package?  Why can't you just find a Git installer package on the internet anywhere that is not only labeled 2.0+  , but the installation archive you download is also labeled as such?

For example:  This [2.1.3 site](http://git-scm.com/downloads)  takes you to this [1.9.4 site](http://git-scm.com/download/win) download.

Comment: It looks like you're on Windows; I don't think that Git 2.x has been officially released for Windows yet, at least not as pre-compiled binaries.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It is not clear that that is the case and the site is misleading, making you think your getting 2.1.3, but you don't.

Comment: I have edited my answer below: Git for Windows 2.3.5 is available.

Comment: Git-For-Windows is now on par with Git itself: 2.4.4 is available.

Comment: The http://git-scm.com/download/win will now download the latest Git for Windows (2.6.2 at the time of writing).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git for Windows is [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/git/releases) project. The latest version of this project is 1.9.4 so Git is also 1.9.4 in it. This is official Git installer for Windows.

Also there is a note on [download page](http://git-scm.com/download/win):

> The current source code release is version 2.1.3. If you want the newer version, you can build it from the source code.

So you can build Git 2+ on Windows by yourself.

Answer (score 57):

There is a new project called "**Git For Windows**": https://git-for-windows.github.io/

As I explained, [it will replace msysgit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309), with the [phasing out of msysgit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784743/6309) (Q4 2015) and the new [Git For Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) (Q2 2015).

It has a much more recent bash, based on the 64bits [`msys2` project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/), an independent rewrite of MSYS, based on modern Cygwin (POSIX compatibility layer) and MinGW-w64, with the aim of better interoperability with native Windows software.
`msys2` comes with [its own installer](https://msys2.github.io/) too.

The git bash is now (with the new Git For Windows 2.6.x):

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

(as opposed to the old 32-bits msys bash from Git for Windows 1.9.5:
`GNU bash, version 3.1.20(4)-release (i686-pc-msys) 2005`).

This 4.3 bash comes with [the latest patches](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/?C=M;O=D).

You can [install the SDK](https://github.com/git-for-windows/sdk/releases) in order to build a [git 2.x](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
(The SDK will bring the right git sources)

Update 2015: you now can test on Windows the latest Git releases (2.6.2+ at the moment): https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/.

Comment: This allowed me to get the latest version of Git on windows using an installer. Wish I'd seen it sooner.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I wonder why on the official [Git page](https://git-scm.com/) they still offer that old Git for Windows installer.

Comment: @informatik01 because git-for-windows is still consider not stable enough: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/12#issuecomment-111185468. Hopefully, a full switch might occur for Git 2.5.

Comment: @VonC perhaps update and point to the new homepage on https://git-for-windows.github.io/ - the git-scm.com downloads now also point to these new builds anyhow.

Comment: @ThomasFerrisNicolaisen Thank you: here is my edit for your review: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26826359/revisions. Note that you can also edit any answer you want (your edit will be reviewed, but you are so close to http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)