# Why git under cygwin asks for password?

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I correctly pointed to key file in ssh config:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host <host>
        IdentityFile /cygdrive/v/poma.pem

$ ssh git@<host>
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Roman!
Connection to <host> closed.
```

and using cygwin's git

```
$ which git
/usr/bin/git

$ git --version
git version 2.1.4

$ /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/git.exe --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
```

But when I try to push it displays a password prompt:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@<host>:poma/deploy.git (fetch)
origin  git@<host>:poma/deploy.git (push)

$ git push -u origin master
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: You say it displays a password prompt, but I don't see one in the text you pasted.

Comment: Because it is displayed in a window

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, try doing the same setup (~/.ssh/config) on Windows only (no cygwin, with the latest git-for-windows (unzip anywhere you want [`PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.4.windows.2/PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe), and you got git 2.4.4: [see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309))

By using a git-cmd.exe (or git-bash.exe), you will get an environment where HOME has been set to your `%USERPROFILE%`.
In it, put your .ssh/config file, and try again pushing from your repo.