# Using git with SSH-key on Windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am connecting to my virtual machine with ssh like this:

```
ssh -i keyfile.key user@server.com
```

I have created a git repository on the server which I want to push to, but I do nott know how I should use the keyfile.key with git.

I am supposed to execute the command:

```
git push live master
```

But I getting the error "permission denied (publickey)", so how do I specify the key? I am on Windows 8.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- use a, `~/.ssh/config` ([check where `%HOME%` is set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30995011/6309), since you are on Windows).
  The config file [would look like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20791214/6309) (replace `<hostkey>` by any string you want)

  ```
  Host <hostkey>
    HostName myserver
    User user
    IdentityFile C:\path\to\.ssh\keyfile.key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
  ```
- change your remote url to one using the config Host key

  ```
  git rmeote set-url list <hostkey>:myrepo
  ```