# ssh-add Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: ssh, git-bash, ssh-agent

I'm having a little issue with my ssh-agent. 
Indeed I can't make it work and I don't understand why.

This is the console's output :

[image: http://hpics.li/807f3fe]

I'm sure that ssh agent is running. 
For your information I'm on Windows 7 and I tried to run the gitbash with administrator permissions, but that did not changed anything. Also everything worked fine until yesterday, and I did not changed anything.

Do you guys have any ideas why ?

Comment: I think this could better be answered on some other Q&A, e.g. serverfault.com or superuser.com

Answer (score -2):

Simply upgrade to the latest [git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) ([with a more recent bash, while msysgit is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309))

Unzip [`PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit` to your path.

Then call `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit\git-bash.exe`, and you are good to go.

Check the value of $HOME (`echo $HOME`) and check it is a folder you have the right to write, where there is `~/.ssh` with `gitlab` and `gitlab.pub`.