# gitlab: Windows: How to use chmod and fix "Get Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository"

Tags: git, bash, gitlab, git-bash

I have gone through many other posts about the above error, but they all seem to be for a different OS, or for some different reason.

I am running Windows 8.1. I have git installed (I am very new to git), and have signed up to gitlab, create a project there, created and added the key (as per instructions), however when I try and do a push, I get the

```
Pushing to git@gitlab.com:myusername/Test1.git
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now when I created my ssh key using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@gmail.com
```

it did create the files in the local project folder, and not under C:\Users\Peter (my home folder)

So, copied the single file (known_hosts) I deleted the existing .ssh folder, and created using bash, and then copied in the above together with the created id_rsa.pub and idrsa.key files.

From Git Gui, if I go to Help | Show SSH Key is reports "Found a public key in ~/.ssh/id_ras.pub

From bash, my permissions on the folder are.

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 Peter    Administ        0 Jun 14 09:35 .ssh
```

and the permissions on the files within are..

```
$ ls .ssh  -l
total 2
-rw-r--r--    1 Peter    Administ      403 Jun 13 18:26 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 Peter    Administ     1766 Jun 13 18:26 idrsa.key
-rw-r--r--    1 Peter    Administ      184 Jun 13 18:11 known_hosts
```

I am assuming I need to fix the permissions here?

So I go into the .ssh folder and try a 
    chmod 777 *

But then when I use ls -l to see the permissions they have not changed

Likewise when I try that on the actual directory .ssh, permissions stay as they are

**So, the questions are**

1. Am I on the right track here, is it the permissions of the folder/files that are the problem
2. If so, how can I fix this (on Windows 8.1)

I am at a complete loss of what to try next

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I on the right track here, is it the permissions of the folder/files that are the problem

Not really: "permission denied" is sent back by the GitLab server, as it doesn't recognize your ssh public key.

Firstly, as mentioned in [GitLab ssh keys doc page](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html):

> Copy-paste the key (`id_rsa.pub` content) to the 'My SSH Keys' section under the 'SSH' tab in your user profile. Please copy the complete key starting with ssh- and ending with your username and host.

Secondly, ssh will locally look for the private and public keys in `%HOME%`.
And `%HOME%` isn't defined by default in Git, unless you launch `git-cmd.exe` or `git-bash.exe` packaged with the latest Git for Windows 2.4.x+.

So:

- make sure to grep [PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe), and unzip it anywhere you want (for example in: c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit)
  Don't intall the [old obsolete msysgit 1.9.5 from git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/download/win). As [I explained, it will soon be phased out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309).
- add `c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit\usr\bin` to your %PATH% (it includes `ssh.exe`)
- launch `c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit\git-cmd.exe`, and see that  `%HOME%` is define (`set HOME`).
  It should be defined to your `%USERPROFILE%` by default (`c:\Users\<yourLogin>`)
- generate your ssh keys (or copy your existing one in `%HOME%\.ssh`). Don't worry about chmod or rights.
- make sure your ssh public key is copied in your GitLab ssh key page.

Then, test if ssh works:

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com
```

*Now* you can start pushing.

Comment: Hi Vonc, thanks for your reply and details information. I went though all of the above, installed the above, added the dir to the path, made sure HOME was defined and correct. I regenerated the key, and added it to gitlab. I now got further. The ssh -Tv git@gitlab.co seemed to succeed. I also created a new project, But trying to push from Git Gui I now get "fatal: https://gitlab.com/myusername/test2/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
Pushing to https://gitlab.com/myusername/test2". Also, when I open bash from git gui it reports Welcome to Git (version 1.9.5-preview20141217)

Comment: @peterc if we are talking about ssh, make sure your url you are pushing to is not an https one. `git remote -v` will show you the current `origin` url, and `git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:myusername/test2` would set a more classic ssh url to `origin`.

Comment: Hi @VonC, yes my problem was I was using https. I tried just `git@gitlab.com:myusername/test2` without the https and it pushed up my test file perfectly. Thankyou very much for your help!