# sh.exe has stopped working on windows 8

Tags: git, git-bash

When I type `git` from command line all is working fine.
But When I try to run Git Bash, I'm getting error sh.exe has stopped working
Details:

Problem signature:

```
Problem Event Name: BEX
Application Name:   sh.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  550b4e9e
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_5861
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
Exception Offset:   PCH_78_FROM_ntdll+0x0003CA2C
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Data: 00000008
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.4
Locale ID:  1058
Additional Information 1:   5861
Additional Information 2:   5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
Additional Information 3:   a10f
Additional Information 4:   a10ff7d2bb2516fdc753f9c34fc3b069

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy   statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Meanwhile all was working fine 3-4 days ago. I installed composer, xampp and Postgres during this time and English MUI for Visual Studio 2012. Reinstalling don't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a more recent git bash and `sh.exe` from the new Git for Windows [`PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.4.windows.2/PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe) (released 4 hours ago)

Simply uncompress it anywhere you want, and add `c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit\cmd` to the `%PATH%`.

Also, launch Git bash (`c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit\git-bash.exe`), and see if the issue persists.

I explain why that 64-bits version of the new Git for Windows came to be in "[Why is it that if you download Git 2.0 from the net, you always get a 1.9.4 installer package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309)".

Comment: Thanks, not the best solution that I expected, but rather works and I can continue with my work.