# directory created by GitBash doesn't appear in Windows explorer

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, windows-explorer

Hi I'm working with GitBash to create a directory for my project, and then to clone the project from GitHub.com/... 
But the directory never appeared in Windows Explorer.

To be detailed:

1. I create a directory using `mkdir TestForStackOverFlow`
2. I clone the project from GitHub.com using `git clone https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2.git`

but i can't access this directory with windows explorer.

Images proving:
Before `mkdir TestForStackOverflow`
[image: Before <code>mkdir TestForStackOverflow</code>]

After `mkdir TestForStackOverflow`
[image: After <code>mkdir TestForStackOverflow</code>]

Any guess how to fix it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Git can not track empty directories. Your question is unclear for me.

Comment: Check your title for spelling errors

Comment: I do not know why it happens, sorry.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing: the directory open in Windows Explorer, with at least one folder created in Explorer; and a bash session with the same directory as the cwd, with a `mkdir` and `ls` in the history to prove that the Explorer-created directory *is* visible there?

Comment: @o11c I add 2 screenshots..thanks for interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was the COMODO firewall (version 6.2.282872.2847) who "auto sandbox" the GitBash without asking me.

I mark C:/Program Files/Git folder as Trusted and everything runs fine!

To do this on COMODO there is the steps:

1. Open COMODO firewall and move to Task by clicking the up-right Icon as showing in the next image (red arrow)

[image: Switch to Tasks]

2. In the Task screen choose Shadowbox Tasks and then click Open Advanced Settings

[image]

3. In the new window on left menu choose File Rating -> Trusted Files. In the list will appear open the pop-up menu on the bottom of the list (the little up-arrow on the bottom).

[image]

4. Choose Add > Folders, navigate to the Git Folder and press OK. Finally press OK to Advanced Settings window.

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if the issue persists when using a [more recent bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309), namely the one package with the latest [`git-for-windows`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/) (successor to msysgit)

Unzip [`PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.4.windows.2/PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe) and launch its `git-bash.exe`.
You will be using Git 2.4.4. On Windows.

Comment: Actually was the COMODO firewall who "sandbox" the GitBash without asking me. I mark `C:/Programfiles/Git` folder as Trusted and everything runs fine!
Should I post this solution as answer?

Comment: @Universe Absolutely: you can answer your own questions: it will help the community.

Comment: Anyway before I figured out, I tried your approach and I'm going to use the Git-for-windows you proposed me, thanks.