# Git bash screen became black

Tags: git, git-bash

My git bash screen doesn't show anything as shown in picture below. I have uninstalled and re-installed and it didn't work. I would greatly appreciate if any one could help on this. I am using Windows 8.

**Updates:**

On looking into EventViewer as per the suggestion in comments it says that
`libssl.dll, libcurl.dll,libcrypto.dll and libicon-2.dll` are missing. But, I see that these are already in bin folder. Any idea?

I have Git 1.9.5 Preview201.exe (the most recent one) from msysgit.github.io.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click on that console, and then press `control-c`?

Comment: @vgoff: Thanks. Nothing happens. I see only the dash in motion.Do you need any extra information?.

Comment: @Downvoters: It would be nice if you leave comments so that I can provide details.

Comment: Did this work previously, and now it suddenly fails?  Or is this a new install?  What version?

Comment: I did not downvote, but was tempted, so I left a message to hopefully prompt you to give more information.  As it stands, it still is very hard to imagine what you have tried, what has failed, what processes may be running under that terminal.  I am not surprised you got a few downvotes though.  Hard to help, frustrating as it is for you, when there is very little information to go on.  That "dash in motion" is your cursor by the way. ;)

Comment: @EdwardThomson: Yes, it worked for three time (since I installed), but then it just shows the blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, try the [much more recent bash (2013 vs. 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309) which is packed with [git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/).

No setup required, just unzip [`PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.5.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe), and call:

```
 c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit\git-bash.exe
```

[image: git bash 2.4.5]

Comment: This is so perfect. It worked for me. I will uninstall the one I installed from https://msysgit.github.io/.. Thank you very much.