# Can't do git push/pull on Cygwin: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: git, cygwin, git-push, git-pull

So I installed git on Cygwin and everything is great, *except* anything to do with remotes. When I try either to push or pull anything, I get the following error:

`/usr/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I also have git bash installed, but since that installation doesn't connect with Cygwin, I had to use apt-cyg to get it to work in Cygwin. I can push/pull in git bash or in the GitHub GUI no problem (they don't clash or anything), but I'd really like to get the Cygwin version working, since I do other stuff there and it is annoying to change terminals all the time!

Comment: I used cygwin's `git` all the time. I've never had to do anything but install it through `setup.exe`. It might somehow be missing an SSL library? I don't know how to list the cygwin packages I have installed.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea! I'm being forced to use Windows at work :( What I do can tell you is that I had Cygwin installed prior to installing git (via setup.exe) and after I did, I couldn't use it, hence apt-cyg...

Answer (score 1):

You can try the same Git operations *without* Cygwin, using [the latest git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) (with its portable distro [`PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.5.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe): extract it anywhere you want)

Its `c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit\git-bash.exe` calls a [fairly recent bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309), and has most of the Linux command a Cygwin shell has, allowing you to stay in that shell.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help, but the question is about getting git to work in Cygwin. I reinstalled Cygwin and everything works now, but it would have been nice to avoid that.

Comment: @FelipeGerard sure but you really don't need to use an old and obsolete Git in Cygwin while you have a modern one for Windows.

Comment: That's true. I'll check if it has all the packages I need and if so I'll give it a try. One thing I do wish git bash had was the ability to horizontaly resize the window. I know it is silly, but I do a ton of things in the terminal and find having to work in 1/4 of my screen really frustrating :( I can't help but say yay Mac/Linux, boohoo Windows.

Comment: So I tried git for windows and it looks promising! Resizable window and everything. I'll get back at you when I have had more time to try it.

Comment: @FelipeGerard sounds great! I have been using it for a few month now, and I am quite satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The cause turned on to be a non-existent path in `$PATH` environment variable. While verifying git binary with `cygcheck`, I was getting the following output:

```
$ cygcheck 'C:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https.exe'
C:\cygwin64\usr\libexec\git-core\git-remote-https.exe
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
cygcheck: WARNING: PATH is not set

cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygcurl-4.dll

cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygwin1.dll

cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygiconv-2.dll

cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygintl-8.dll

cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygpcre-1.dll

cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygz.dll
```

Removing incorrect portion from `$PATH` solved the problem.