# Bash: =~ and pattern matching in Git Bash 3.1

Tags: bash, git-bash

I basically want to do the following in Bash 3.1 under Windows (Git Bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nocasematch

declare file='[Vol 01] - 04 - This message'
declare filesafe="${file}"

declare pattern='\[Vol ([0-9]+)\] - ([0-9]+) -*'
if [[ "${file}" =~ $pattern ]]; then
  echo "regexp: $(printf "%s %-2d %-3d" "${filesafe}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ) - - -"
else
        echo "failed: $(printf "%s" "${filesafe}") - - - - -"
fi
```

The `=~` does not work because it does not exists in this version of Bash.

Note: the script works with Bash 4.3.33 in Gentoo.

Version of Git & Bash are the following:

```
$ git --version ; bash --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
GNU bash, version 3.1.23(6)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

In the sole documentation on Bash 3.1 that I could find, the version is:

> This is Edition 3.1-beta1, last updated 5 September 2005, of The GNU
>   Bash Reference Manual, for Bash, Version **3.1-beta1**.

This documentation state the `=~` is available:

> An additional binary operator, '=~', is available, with the same
>   precedence as '==' and '!='.

Did I miss something like some option using shopt?

Comment: just a side note, don't include your pattern inside quotes.

Comment: @anubhava, ...should, in theory, but the msys build of bash shipped by that vintage of Git for Windows is missing other features available in upstream as well -- try using process substitution, f'rinstance.

Comment: File is some file like {{[Vol 02] - 0001 - Volume 2 chapter 1}}.
However, my question lies more in the implementation of =~ operator in Git Bash under Windows, the code is just an example where it fails rather explicitly (like "I don't recognize =~ dude!").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a more recent version of that bash: use **[git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/)**, which will soon replace the obsolete msysgit.

No setup required: uncompress [`PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and call `c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit\git-bash.exe`.

[You will get a 2013 4.3.39 bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309) (instead of the old 2005 3.1.20 bash of msysgit): that is one of the very [latest 4.3 patches](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/?C=M;O=D), May 2015.

That is more than enough to make `=~` work.

Comment: Is there a list of supported version of Windows ? I'm stuck with XP at work, and while the script (and my question) is for something at home, I'm really interested to switch to git-for-windows now.

Comment: @NoDataFound Xp works just fine. Just uncompress the 32-bits version. https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-32-bit.7z.exe