# Why are there no releases of Git for Windows, but only pre-releases instead?

Tags: windows, git

I got to know that msysgit [is phased out](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Relationship-to-Git-for-Windows). But when looking at the [release page of Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), I only see pre-releases. So why are there no final releases of Git for Windows?

Comment: As the release titles say, they are *release candidates*. The project is still young and these are the first ever releases, so there’s bound to be a few problems which first need to be solved before the releases become final and recommended for everyone to use.

Comment: The release is now out: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.5.0.windows.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [issue 12](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/12#issuecomment-111185468): the new "git for Windows" is not yet stable enough.
I mentioned it in "[Why is it that if you download Git 2.0 from the net, you always get a 1.9.4 installer package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309)".

Git (for Windows) 2.5 itself still has issue just to be compiled ([issues/257](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/257))

**EDIT:**
The first release of Git for Windows is [now (August 18th, 2015) available](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.5.0.windows.1).

Comment: From the link to issue 12 I found that there is the milestone [First release of Git for Windows generated using the new SDK](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/milestones/First%20release%20of%20Git%20for%20Windows%20generated%20using%20the%20new%20SDK) which has at the time of writing 4 open issues.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Exactly, including the 257 I mention in the answer.