# using assist on Git Bash

Tags: windows, git, bash, git-bash

I use `Windows 7`.What is the correct way to use `help` in `Git Bash`?

```
help command
```

or

```
command --help
```

For example:

I have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to break result of below command

```
$ while --help
>
```

But this works:

```
$ help while
while: while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
     Expand and execute COMMANDS as long as the final command in the
    `while' COMMANDS has an exit status of zero.
```

Or

```
$ help touch
sh.exe": help: no help topics match `touch'.  Try `help help' or `man -k touch'
or `info touch'.
```

But

```
$ touch --help
Usage: touch [OPTION]... FILE...
  or:  touch [-acm] MMDDhhmm[YY] FILE... (obsolescent)
...
```

I looked at [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/).But I do not find any thing in about using `help` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [How to Get Help With a Command from the Linux Terminal](http://www.howtogeek.com/108890/how-to-get-help-with-a-command-from-the-linux-terminal-8-tricks-for-beginners-pros-alike/), `help` is only for a short list of the commands built into the Bash shell itself. `touch` is not one of them.

For git commands, you would call `git help <command>` (like `git help checkout`).

Make sure to use `git-bash.exe` packaged with the [latest release from git-for-windows](http://%20short%20list%20of%20the%20commands%20built%20into%20the%20Bash%20shell%20itself): its bash is significantly more recent than [the old msysgit one](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases).
See "[Why is it that if you download Git 2.0 from the net, you always get a 1.9.4 installer package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309)".