# Can't type in Git Bash if I select another window in Windows

Tags: git, bash, homestead

I'm running a Laravel Homestead VM in Git Bash, and every time I select another window to do something else, I can't return to Git Bash -- typing doesn't work (but it does in other windows).

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10. If I type "exit" followed be hitting Enter, the cursor issue is solved. but then I'm also kicked out of the Virtual Machine I was in.

Comment: So you can type, but the typing is invisible?  Does typing `reset` bring your typing back?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using the latest bash from the [latest git for Windows (2.5.3)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/). It has a [more recent bash than the old msysgit one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309).

If that still fail, consider using a VirtualBox+Vagrant, as [in this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-get-homestead-vagrant-vm-running/).

Answer (score 0):

No clue what the solution is, but hitting `ctrl+C` to Cancel current process stops that issue. But it also stops the current process :S

Comment: Do you still see the issue with a git 2.8.3? (soon 2.8.4)

Comment: I'm running 2.8.1 I'll update and let you know next time I use it!