# How can I add binaries to git bash?

Tags: git, windows-shell, git-bash

We have path environment variable in windows which holds the places for binaries.
How can we add some binaries to git bash?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to modify `$PATH` in your git bash shell session:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/path/to/binary
```

You can do so in a `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Make sure you are using the latest bash from the [latest git for Windows (2.5.3)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/). It has a [more recent bash than the old msysgit one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309).