# Git not recognizing alias

Tags: git, bash, alias

My `.gitconfig` file is as follows:

```
[user]
    name = myname
    email = asdf@xyz.com
[alias]
    co = commit -am
```

When I'm in Git Bash and I enter:

```
git co "Macro changes"
```

I get this error message:

```
git: 'co' is not a git command.
```

Why isn't the alias being recognized?

EDIT: I'm running Windows 7.  The `.gitconfig` file is at `C:\Users\[myuserID]\.gitconfig`.

Strangely, I just created another alias:

```
git config --global alias.st status
```

Then I ran

```
git st
```

which worked.  But when I opened `C:\Users\[myuserID]\.gitconfig`, the new alias wasn't listed there.  So maybe the global config file is somewhere else?

In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\profile`, there's this definition of `HOME`:

```
# Set up USER's home directory
if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
  HOME="$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH"
  if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
    HOME="$USERPROFILE"
  fi
fi
```

Windows command prompt tells me that `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH` is `P:\`, and sure enough, the new alias `st = status` is in a `.gitconfig` file there, but not `co = commit -am`, which is odd because when I created the `co` alias yesterday, I was able to successfully call it.

Comment: Try editing the .gitconfig in P:\ and restart git. When you create an alias on the command-line, it will be remembered in that session. The commandline environment will not update the .gitconfig file.

Comment: @WalterA, editing `P:\.gitconfig` did allow me to run that alias in a subsequent git session.  It seems odd to me that the command line updated the `C:\ ` version of `.gitconfig` yesterday, but today it updated the `P:\ ` version.

Comment: Can you check the (Computer icon/select Properties/advanced) environment variables ? Are HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH set in the USER or in the SYSTEM variables ? And did you start the commandline window both times the same way (right-mouse bash-here/start-run cmd) ?

Comment: @WalterA, they are not set in USER or SYSTEM; in all cases I started the command line window using **right click->Git Bash**.

Comment: The only explanation I can see is that you right-clicked in the explorer when the current drive was P: today and was C: yesterday. For the next few days, examine the value of %HOMEDRIVE% just after creating a commandline window.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check the value of `$HOME` in your git bash.

If it refers to `C:\Users\[myuserID]`, *then* your aliases will be recognized.

Also make sure you are using the latest bash ([not the old one from msysgit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309)): unzip [`PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit` to your path.

Then call `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.2-64-bit\git-bash.exe`, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Bash on windows almost implies that you are using cygwin, right?

If so then the cygwin version of git expects the global .gitconfig file to be placed at the cygwin user's home directory, e.g. `c:\cygwin\home\username\.gitconfig` or wherever cygwin is installed (run `echo $HOME/.gitconfig` to get exact value).

Edit: With the update on the git installation path of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git` it is clearly not the cygwin git, but as you have figured out it also uses environmental variable HOME as target for storage of the global .gitconfig, although with a different value.

Regarding *when I created the co alias yesterday, I was able to successfully call it*, could it be that you added that alias to a .gitconfig file inside a repository?

Comment: I thought about that, but I remembered running `git config --global` when I created the alias; indeed, my `C:\Users\[myuserID]\.bash_history` log (which has all of yesterday's bash commands) includes `git config --global alias.co 'commit -am'`.  And neither of the `config` files from repos I was working in yesterday have the alias, it's only in `C:\Users\[myuserID]\.gitconfig`.