# Trying to run a script that extends GIT

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I've saved the following as an .sh file and executed it from my root directory: https://gist.github.com/emiller/6769886

Got a couple of errors:

```
script.sh: line 65: conditional binary operator expected
script.sh: line 65: syntax error near `=~'
script.sh: line 65: `while [[ $1 =~ ^\- ]]; do'
```

And then when I ran the git-rewrite-history command I received an error:

```
'git-rewrite-history' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Would appreciate help, 0 linux experience here.

Thanks.

Edit - I'm using bash from windows, which is probably related to the issue.
Will attempt on a Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 'git-rewrite-history' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>  operable program or batch file.
> ```

You need to set the script execution permissions:

```
chmod 777 path/to/git-rewrite-history
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment although it doesn't work for me.
Please view my OP edit.

Answer (score 0):

A bash script named `git-rewrite-history` (even on Windows) must be executed with:

```
git rewrite-history
```

Any script named `git-xxx` can be called that way (`git xxx`), as long as `git-xxx` is in a folder referenced by your `%PATH%` environment variable.
The bash script will be executed in the [msys2 bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309) git session, even when called from a simple Windows CMD shell session.
You do not need Cygwin at all.