# Why does Git version 2.7.0 appear as 1.9.4.msysgit.2 in command line?

Tags: git

Running Windows 10, I downloaded Git at https://git-scm.com, but when entering "git version" in the command prompt it returns `1.9.4.msysgit.2`.

I've reinstalled and restarted multiple times but it keeps displaying the older version. What are some possible causes and solutions to make sure I'm running the 2.7.0?

Answer (score 1):

Check you `%PATH%` environment variable: it is likely that the [32 bits 1.9.4 Git](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) comes before the [64 bits 2.7.0 Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

The [bash is more recent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309), based on the [64bits msys2 project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have them both installed on your machine.

Try to uninstall the old version or both of them if you wish and then install the latest once.

Then verify that you have the desired version:

[image]